# How to add these user custom actions in site/subsite using CSOM in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, pnp

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pnp:ProvisioningTemplate ID="CommandUIRibbonSamples" Version="1" xmlns:pnp="http://schemas.dev.office.com/PnP/2015/12/ProvisioningSchema">
  <pnp:CustomActions>
    <pnp:SiteCustomActions>
      <pnp:CustomAction Name="CA_4" Description="ca 4" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" RegistrationType="List" RegistrationId="101" Title="CA 4 Title" Sequence="6000" Enabled="true">
        <pnp:CommandUIExtension>
          <CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Copies.Controls._children">
              <Button
                Id="Ribbon.Documents.Copies.OfficeDevPnPDownloadAll"
                Command="OfficeDevPnP.Cmd.DownloadAll"
                Image16by16="/_layouts/15/images/sharepointfoundation16.png"
                LabelText="Download All"
                Description="Download all files separately"
                ToolTipTitle="Download All"
                ToolTipDescription="Download all files separately"
                TemplateAlias="o1"
                Sequence="15"/>
            </CommandUIDefinition>
          </CommandUIDefinitions>
          <CommandUIHandlers>
            <CommandUIHandler
              Command="OfficeDevPnP.Cmd.DownloadAll"
              CommandAction="https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/pages/index.aspx" />
          </CommandUIHandlers>
        </pnp:CommandUIExtension>
      </pnp:CustomAction>
      <pnp:CustomAction Name="CA_6" Description="ca 6" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" RegistrationType="ContentType" RegistrationId="0x0101" Title="CA 6 Title" Sequence="5000" Enabled="true">
        <pnp:CommandUIExtension>
            <CommandUIDefinitions>
              <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Tabs._children">
                <Tab Id="Custom Tab" Title="Custom Tab" Description="Custom Tab">
                  <Scaling Id="Custom Tab.Scaling">
                    <MaxSize Id="Custom Group.Scaling.MaxSize" GroupId="Custom Group" Size="TwoLarge" />
                    <MaxSize Id="Custom Group 2.Scaling.MaxSize" GroupId="Custom Group 2" Size="OneLarge" />
                    <Scale Id="Custom Group.Scaling.Scale" GroupId="Custom Group" Size="TwoLarge" />
                    <Scale Id="Custom Group 2.Scaling.Scale" GroupId="Custom Group 2" Size="OneLarge" />
                  </Scaling>
                  <Groups Id="Custom Tab.Groups">
                    <Group Id="Custom Group 2" Title="Custom Group 2" Description="Custom Group 2" Sequence="7888" Template="Ribbon.Templates.OneLarge">
                      <Controls Id="Custom Group 2.Controls">
                        <Button Id="CustomButton3" LabelText="Custom Button 3" Image16by16="/_layouts/15/images/attach16.png" Image32by32="/_layouts/15/images/attach16.png" ToolTipTitle="Custom Button 3" ToolTipDescription="Custom Button 3" Command="CustomButton3.Command" TemplateAlias="c3" />
                      </Controls>
                    </Group>
                    <Group Id="Custom Group" Title="Custom Group 1" Description="Custom Group 1" Sequence="10000" Template="Ribbon.Templates.TwoLarge">
                      <Controls Id="Custom Group 1.Controls">
                        <Button Id="CustomButton1" LabelText="Custom Button 1" Image16by16="/_layouts/15/images/itslidelibrary.png" Image32by32="/_layouts/15/images/itslidelibrary.png" ToolTipTitle="Custom Button 1" ToolTipDescription="Custom Button 1" Command="CustomButton1.Command" TemplateAlias="c1" />
                        <Button Id="CustomButton2" LabelText="Custom Button 2" Image16by16="/_layouts/15/images/dldsln16.png" Image32by32="/_layouts/15/images/dldsln16.png" ToolTipTitle="Custom Button 2" ToolTipDescription="Custom Button 2" Command="CustomButton2.Command" TemplateAlias="c2" />
                      </Controls>
                    </Group>
                  </Groups>
                </Tab>
              </CommandUIDefinition>
              <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
                <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.TwoLarge">
                  <Layout Title="TwoLarge" LayoutTitle="TwoLarge"> 
                    <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow"> 
                      <Row> 
                        <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="c1" /> 
                        <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="c2" /> 
                      </Row> 
                    </Section> 
                  </Layout> 
                </GroupTemplate>
              </CommandUIDefinition>
              <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
                <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.OneLarge">
                  <Layout Title="OneLarge" LayoutTitle="OneLarge"> 
                    <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow"> 
                      <Row> 
                        <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="c3" /> 
                      </Row> 
                    </Section> 
                  </Layout> 
                </GroupTemplate>
              </CommandUIDefinition>
            </CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIHandlers>
              <CommandUIHandler Command="CustomButton1.Command" CommandAction="https://www.google.com" />
              <CommandUIHandler Command="CustomButton2.Command" CommandAction="http://www.bing.com" />
              <CommandUIHandler Command="CustomButton3.Command" CommandAction="http://dev.office.com/sharepoint" />
            </CommandUIHandlers>
        </pnp:CommandUIExtension>
      </pnp:CustomAction>
    </pnp:SiteCustomActions>
  </pnp:CustomActions>
</pnp:ProvisioningTemplate>
```

---

I'm adding above PnP custom action using following code. but it won't work! any Suggestions?

```
string xmlFileName = @"TestXml.xml";
string xmlFilePath = @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\";

OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager authMgr = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();

var provisioningProvider = new XMLFileSystemTemplateProvider(xmlFilePath, String.Empty);
var provisioningTemplate = provisioningProvider.GetTemplate(xmlFileName);
provisioningTemplate.Connector.Parameters[FileConnectorBase.CONNECTIONSTRING] = xmlFilePath;

using (var ctx = authMgr.GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(OnlinePWA, UserName, Passwords))
{
    ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
    ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();

    ctx.Web.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(provisioningTemplate);
    ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom action by CSOM in SharePoint online, we could use C# and JavaScript.

We can add the custom action in the item ECB menu and ribbon menus for Custom List, Document Library and Calendar.

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

Custom Actions Using CSOM For SharePoint Online

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-actions-using-csom-for-sharepoint-online/

Custom Actions Using CSOM For SharePoint Online - Part Two.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-actions-using-csom-for-sharepoint-online-part-2/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not working for the pnp:ProvisioningTemplate.

Can you have the Solution for the above pnp xml ? using OfficeDevPnP.Core for SharePoint Online!

Comment: You can apply this PnP provisioning template to a site using the PnP Core library or PnP PowerShell. 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries